# load a view in a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, view, controller

I'm trying this ([Using Jquery in Codeignitor app to update div every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869834/using-jquery-in-codeignitor-app-to-update-div-every-10-seconds/19454244#19454244)), it is working but it shows my whole view in my div

I work with hooks and I have a masterview where I load other views in it...

When I load my controller in to my div, it shows my masterview in my div with the view I request in my controller.

How can I just show the requested view without my masterview? Can you help me?

thnx Cheers

Comment: 1. Where is your code? 2. You posted a question as an answer in that other persons question.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  As RUJordan pointed out, in order to help you, we still need to be able to see the code you are having a problem with in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that I've used in CI is to implement a check in the controller to see whether this is an AJAX request. If so, I load the view with data into a variable and return it to the browser as a chunk of html.

```
if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{

    $view_result = $this->load->view('child_view_for_div', $data,true);
    echo($view_result);
}
else
{
    //Return view with master template
}
```